# How can i show additional information of a product on a seperate page through coding

Tags: magento-1.7, additional-information

Can anybody please help me to provide a code that show the additional information of a product on a sepecrate page...

If there is any php code, please let me know so i can use that..

I am not fiding any proper code..

IF possible how can i change this code in a way that i can use it on any seperate page against a specific product id.

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>
    <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
        <col width="25%" />
        <col />
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Please help me..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Using your existing code. You just need to change this,

```
$_product = $this->getProduct()
```

To

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(100)
```

Replace `100` with your product ID.